# Using JRI to simulate R console

Tags: rjava, jri

I need to build an application with JRI that works similarly to the R console. The issue is that sometimes the console will respond displaying a line (for example, after entering `x` below) and sometimes it doesn't (for example, after entering `x = 1`)

[image]

I tried to analyze `eng.parseAndEval(statement)` (where statement is the command entered on the console) but cannot tell when to display the response on the console, and when not. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is the visibility flag maintained by R which tells the regular event loop when to print and when not. See `withVisible` in R for details. However, you really don't want to get into re-implementing the R event loop. Instead, JRI allows you to have R do all the work for you - you just implement the console callbacks `RMainLoopCallbacks` to handle all your console I/O and then start the event loop. You may want to have a look at [JGR](http://rforge.net/JGR/) - it is a Java console implemented using JRI.